# Annotating "zero or more parameters with any type" for Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a function that is the same as `jQuery.noop`, `angular.noop` and `goog.nullFunction`: It does nothing and returns undefined, but it is convenient in the form of `callback(successFn || noop);`.

It can be called with any number of arguments (0 or more) of any type.

This is how I have it currently:

```
/**
 * @param varArgs {...*}
 */
var noop = function(varArgs) {};
```

**Problem:** When called without arguments, Google Closure Compiler gives me this:

```
Function noop: called with 0 argument(s). 
Function requires at least 1 argument(s) and no more than 1 argument(s).
```

The funny thing is that [goog.nullFunction](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/15160ce901b70ac9df5e7d25ae4835835738f782/closure_goog_base.js.source.html#line393)  is annotated for Closure Compiler, but its annotation is also flawed, it throws errors when it's called with one or more arguments:

```
Function noop: called with 1 argument(s).
Function requires at least 0 argument(s) and no more than 0 argument(s).
```

**Question:** How do I annotate my `noop` function properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) the syntax is:

```
/**
 * @param {...*} varArgs
 */
```

You first put the type of variable then it's name. After a test your example does give an error but when using the correct order it doesn't.